# Is "something is passed to someone" correct? Or should it be "something has been passed to someone"?

Tags: grammar

Here's the sentence that I wrote.

The instruction book is passed to her for her perusal.

Is the sentence correct? Or should "is" replace by "has been"? What is the difference between the two?

Thank you.

Comment: What tense are you writing in? If you're writing in the present, then 'is passed' is correct. If you're writing in the past, it's 'the book was passed to her.' ('has been passed' and 'had been passed' could also be correct, but again it depends on context. Look up "English sequence of tenses" and try to figure out what's happening with this sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

They are simply different tenses of "to be passed"

> The instruction book has been passed to her for her perusal

Someone had the book and they passed it to her. This has happened recently and presumably she still has the book.

> The instruction book is passed to her for her perusal

This either acts as a commentary, as for a sporting event, or it describes a regular occurrence, e.g.

Every day, as she enters the library, the book is passed to her for her perusal. We presume that, as she leaves the library, she passes it back.

Comment: "... was passed ..." would be the most appropriate option in most contexts.